# Borders in GEE shifted

Tags: google-earth-engine

[image]I'm relatively new to GEE so the problem is probably me.
I imported Austria from the USDOS/LSIB/2017 (Countries) data set.
The boundaries do not match the boundaries of Google's background map. In order to check whether the borders from the import are correct or not, I imported the borders for Austria from another official data set. But here too the boundaries do not match the Google maps.
Then I tried in vain to reproject in GEE. Apparently my knowledge isn't enough for that...
Maybe I just used the wrong CRS or do I have to reproject?
Or is it something else, perhaps a mistake in thinking?

This is my (short) Code:

```
//Import from USDOS/LSIB/2017 (Countries)
var austria = grenzenDetail.filter(ee.Filter.eq('COUNTRY_NA', 'Austria'));

Map.addLayer(austria.style({color: '#006400', fillColor: '#ff000000'}), {}, 'AUSTRIA');//green Line
Map.addLayer(aut_border, {color: '#fcba03', fillcolor: '#ff000000'},'aut_Border');//in yellow
```

Comment: Can you share the full code with the assets you're using? I added the `USDOS/LSIB/2017` data to the map and it seemed to match fine in that location. https://code.earthengine.google.com/707316917a6e59985b449fd244ac8224

Answer (score 1):

If the asset was uploaded manually, then the projection used during the upload might be causing some issues. For simplicity's sake, I'd suggest using the dataset directly from the GEE catalog. Both the simplified and the detailed versions from there seem to align well with the border.

[image]

```
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
var austria = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Austria'));

var countries2 = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB/2017');
var austria2 = countries2.filter(ee.Filter.eq('COUNTRY_NA', 'Austria'));

Map.addLayer(austria2.style({color: 'red', fillColor: 'red'}), {}, 'AUSTRIA');
Map.addLayer(austria.style({color: '#006400', fillColor: 'green'}), {}, 'AUSTRIA');
```